# Regarding passing a string through a Get and Set Method

Tags: c++, string, constructor, destructor

Let me start off by saying I am a beginner at C++. I am trying to write a program that simply asks the user for 3 inputs. Two are strings and one is an integer. I have written the following class for this :

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Cellphone
{
private :
        string itsbrand;
    string itscolor;
    int itsweight;

public :
    string tostring();
        void setbrand(string brand);
        string getbrand() ;
    void setcolor(string color);
    string getcolor();
    void setweight(int weight);
    int getweight();


};
```

Everything works exactly like I need it except I need two constructors. One without data in the parameters and one with data in the parameters. I am very confused as to were to even begin with constructors so if someone can please provide a little insight I would greatly appreciate it. Here is my main() :

```
int main ()
{
  Cellphone Type;

  int w;
  string b, c;

  cout << "Please enter the Cellphone brand : ";
  getline(cin, b);
  Type.setbrand (b);
  cout << "Please enter the color of the Cellphone : ";
  getline(cin, c);
  Type.setcolor (c);
  cout << "Please enter the weight of the Cellphone in pounds : ";
  cin >> w;
  Type.setweight (w);
  cout << endl;
  cout << Type.tostring();
  cout << endl;
}
```

Any idea on how I would do the constructors?

Comment: [Constructors can be overloaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading#Constructor_overloading), just like any other function in C++.

Comment: It is good practice to declare accessor member functions (those that do not mutate your object) as const e.g. `string getcolor() const;`. If you do not, then your functions cannot be used by member functions of classes which are composed of your class and which *do* declare const. [Click here to see an example I did in ideone](http://ideone.com/1sZwk9).

Answer (score 2):

Constructors in C++ class can be overloaded.

1. The constructor without given parameters are usually called "default
   constructor". If your class does not define any constructor, the
   compiler will generate a "default constructor" for you. "default constructor" is a constructor that can be called without providing any parameter.
2. The constructor with given parameter is used when those parameters
       are provided with value when creating a new object of the class. If
       your class has defined a constructor with parameters, then the
       compiler will not generate a "default constructor" for you, so when
       you create an object that needs a default constructor, it will
       result in compile error. So it is your decision to make whether providing both default constructor and overloaded constructor or not based on your application.

For example, in your CellPhone class, you can provide two or more constructors if you want.

Default constructor: You are providing some kind of default value to members of the class

```
public CellPhone(): itsbrand(""), itscolor(""), itsweight(0){ 
      //note that no formal parameters in CellPhone parameter list
}
```

Constructor with parameters:

```
public CellPhone(string b, string c, int w): itsbrand(b), itscolor(c), itsweight(w)
{
}
```

You can also define a constructor that provides default values for all given parameters, this is also known as "default constructor" by definition, since they have default values. Example given below:

```
public CellPhone(string b="", string c="", int w=0): itsbrand(b),itscolor(c),itsweight(w)
{
}
```

These are some aspects about constructor overloading in C++;

Comment: Thank you that explained a lot for me.